# org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: The job (DEFAULT.tryJob) referenced by the trigger does not exist

Tags: xml, cron, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

My xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<job-scheduling-data version="2.0"
                     xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData
                     http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd">
    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>tryJob</name>
            <group>test_group</group>
            <job-class>HelloJobB</job-class>
            <durability>true</durability>
            <recover>false</recover>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>testTrigger</name>
                <group>test_group</group>
                <description>try</description>
                <job-name>tryJob</job-name>
                <cron-expression>0 57 12 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

and my property file

```
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user = quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password = mask1234
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.maxConnections = 9
```

and my main method class file

```
package quartz;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathException;

import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper;
import org.quartz.xml.ValidationException;
import org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.mkyong.io.BufferedReaderExample;

public class JobsWithXML {


    public static Scheduler getScheduler() throws SchedulerException{

        SchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory("server.properties");
        Scheduler scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        return scheduler;
    }

    public static String readFile(String path) throws IOException{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
        while (sCurrentLine != null) {
             sb.append(sCurrentLine);
             sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
        }
       return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         CascadingClassLoadHelper clhelper = new CascadingClassLoadHelper();
         clhelper.initialize();
        XMLSchedulingDataProcessor xmlJobLoader;
        try {
            xmlJobLoader = new XMLSchedulingDataProcessor(clhelper);
            String fileName = JobsWithXML.class.getResource("simpleJobs.xml").getPath();
            InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(readFile(fileName).getBytes()); 
            String systemId = XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.QUARTZ_SYSTEM_ID_JAR_PREFIX;
            Scheduler  scheduler = getScheduler();
            xmlJobLoader.processStreamAndScheduleJobs(inStream, systemId, scheduler);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

when run this main method its always throw exception

```
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: The job (DEFAULT.tryJob) referenced by the trigger does not exist.
    at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.storeTrigger(RAMJobStore.java:420)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:886)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:259)
    at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.scheduleJobs(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:1171)
    at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.processStreamAndScheduleJobs(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:531)
    at quartz.JobsWithXML.main(JobsWithXML.java:58)
```

but in xml file DEFAULT group not use then why its always throw exception when i change job group name default its working but put any name in group name tag its throw exception why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use same data source name in all schedulers property 
you can try unique data source name for for all schedulers